# Combining multiple row values into one row grouping by two column values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to combine multiple columns from the same table, based on two values. (Line and Message Type)

I have multiple rows with repeated Line Numbers, Message, Message Type, and Description.

What I need is one unique row per Line Number. If a line has multiple messages, of the same type, I would like to be able to have all messages for that line (by type) combined into one value.

### What I have:

`+--------+---------+--------------+-------------------+
| Line   | Message | Message Type |    Description    |
+--------+---------+--------------+-------------------+
|      1 | B1      |            6 | Duplicate         |
|      1 | B3      |            6 | Over              |
|      1 | A1      |            1 | NULL              |
|      2 | B2      |            6 | Separate          |
|      2 | A1      |            1 | NULL              |
|      2 | A2      |            1 | NULL              |
+--------+---------+--------------+-------------------+`

### What I am trying to accomplish

`+-------+--------+--------+------------------------------+
| Line  | Type 1 | Type 6 |         Description          |
+-------+--------+--------+------------------------------+
|     1 | A1     | B1,B3  | Duplicate, Over              |
|     2 | A2,A2  | B2     | Separate                     |
+-------+--------+--------+------------------------------+`

I am using Sql Server 2008. Currently I get one row per line number if there is only one value for each type. For example Line 1 above is returned as 3 rows opposed to one row with all values.

In the example above there are a minimal number of values, but the table I am working with is not limited to these values. (For Example, Type 6 may have 3 different values from a list of 50+ possible values.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Sql Server 2008 has an aggregate method for creating comma-separated lists.  You'll have to make your own by making a custom aggregate method.  Take a look at the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182741(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Thank you, but I don't have the permissions to do that. :(

Comment: @MelissaPoste Then you'll need to talk to your DBA.  There's no way to get a comma-delimited list like that without using an aggregate function of some kind.